# Fetching the sub-string from the database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column which contains strings like below.

sourabh@winworldsoft.com

monica@winworldsoft.com

sachin@winworldsoft.com

I need to get the substring from the @ to .(dot)
i have writing some sql but it have fixed length i need the dynamic query to get the sub-string.

select *from registration where email like '%@%';

Sub string Query
select email, substr(email,4,10) from registration;

please and one write query for me.

Comment: Can anybody help me? I would appreciate very much.

Comment: so the result will be `winworldsoft`  for the above data ? what if there some more dots like `sourabh@winworld.soft.com` ?

Comment: If You don't need to search by string between @ to .(dot)
then just select whole string from the `DataBase` and thereafter
You can use RegEx

Comment: Try using nested SUBSTring_INDEX function.
[http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1)), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(email))+1));
```

This will include all dots between @ and the final one (e.g. "someone@a.long.domain.name.com" will result in "a.long.domain.name") as opposed to nested SUBSTRING_INDEX which will only return whats between @ and the first dot (e.g "a").

Answer (score 0):

`substring_index()` is the best approach:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(email, '@', -1), '.', 1)
```

Comment: can i search on backward direction start from . Dot and end with @ for same result