# Fetching the substring from database and store to the table

Tags: php, mysql, database

How I can get part of email? For example I have email sourabh@winworldsoft sourabh@in.pwc.com in table user for column email, I need get just the part of the company name  and store to the same table for column company I use some regular expression , but appeared result was not as I expected in some conditions like sourabh@in.pwc.com . I am using the sub string function I am using the `select`

```
substring_index(substring_index(email, '@', -1), '.', 1)
```

but this will be false for second eamil id. I want to check through the reg- expression is it possible not.Can anybody help me? I would appreciate very much.

Comment: What is your expected output in both the case?

Comment: In both case for example in first email i want to get winworldsoft and in second email id i want to get only pwc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetching the sub-string from the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509760/fetching-the-sub-string-from-the-database)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need:

```
substring_index(substr(email, 1, (length(email)- length(SUBSTRING_INDEX((email), '.', -1))-1)), '@', -1)
```